# Mock database connection python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a file called `redis_db.py` which has code to connect to redis

```
import os
import redis
import sys

class Database:
       def __init__(self, zset_name):
        redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1')
        redis_port = os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT', 6379)

        self.db = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port)
        self.zset_name = zset_name

    def add(self, key):
        try:
            self.db.zadd(self.zset_name, {key: 0})
        except redis.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print("Unable to connect to redis host.")
            sys.exit(0)
```

I have another file called app.py which is like this

```
from flask import Flask
from redis_db import Database

app = Flask(__name__)
db = Database('zset')

@app.route('/add_word/word=<word>')
def add_word(word):
   db.add(word)
   return ("{} added".format(word))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080')
```

Now I am writing unit test for add_word function like this

```
import unittest
import sys
import os
from unittest import mock

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/../api/")
from api import app  # noqa: E402


class Testing(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_add_word(self):
      with mock.patch('app.Database') as mockdb:
         mockdb.return_value.add.return_value = ""
      result = app.add_word('shivam')
      self.assertEqual(result, 'shivam word added.')
```

Issue I am facing is that even though I am mocking the db method call it is still calling the actual method in the class instead of returning mocked values and during testing I am getting error with message `Unable to connect to redis host.`.

Can someone please help me in figuring out how can I mock the redis database calls.

I am using unittest module

Comment: The issue is that you define `db = Database('zset')` on module import, so your mock patch does not affect your `db` variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `db` is defined on module import, so the `mock.patch` does not affect the `db` variable. Either you move the instantiation of
`db` in the `add_word(word)` function or you patch `db` instead of `Database`, e.g.

```
def test_add_word():
    with mock.patch('api.app.db') as mockdb:
        mockdb.add = mock.MagicMock(return_value="your desired return value")
        result = app.add_word('shivam')
    print(result)
```

Note that the call of `add_word` has to be in the `with` block, otherwise the unmocked version is used.

Comment: Nope not working, it is still calling the original code. Also app.py is a flask app, does that affect on the way I should test my application?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, although for the test case you have posted, my test function calls the mocked version. Maybe you are missing some detail about your implementation?

Comment: I have updated my question with exact same code that I have running at my end. I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your exact source code with my updated test function and it worked. Is the `test_add_word` function a method of a class? If yes can you post this class? Also I thought that maybe the double usage of `app` as your flask app and as the module name might cause an issue, although it worked for me.

Comment: I have updated the question with my test code too. I hope this helps as this is making me crazy now. :(

Comment: I updated my answer for your scenario, I added `api.` to `api.add.db` as you import app from `api`.